# Call MyCustomReceiver instead of default Receiver using Parse.com in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to implement MyCustomReceiver on my android phone, I am sending (by switching msg to JSON ) JSON like below

```
{
"channels": [
  "Giants"
],
"data": {
  "action": "com.example.parsedemo.UPDATE_STATUS",
  "alert": "Ricky Vaughn was injured in last"

}
}
```

in AndroidMenifiest.xml file

```
    android:name="com.example.parsedemo.MyCustomReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.parsedemo.UPDATE_STATUS" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but i am unable to receiving notification using that :( only default receiver is called :(

Answer (score 0):

Siddhhpura, can you have a look at [this](https://github.com/chiangtor/ParseCom-Android-Sample) example.